# increase navigation drawer custom icon's size which is used for opening the drawer

Tags: android

I have added custom icon to my drawerArrowDrawable , but its size is too small. I want the icons size to be increased.

below is my code snippet,

```
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
 toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.sidemenu_btn);
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: what's the size of the image ?

Comment: Check material design specification link for icon size. It should be 24*24.